# Blow up and critical points of the projection map

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, complex-geometry, blow-ups

Denote $Z=V(x_1, \dots, x_{n-1}) \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ and let $Bl_Z(\mathbb{C}^n)$ be the blow up of $\mathbb{C}^n$ along $Z$ together with the projection map $\pi \colon Bl_Z(\mathbb{C}^n) \to \mathbb{C}^n$.

Let $X$ be a singular hypersurface such that $\text{Sing}(X)=Z$. Assume that the the restriction of $\pi$ to $\tilde{X} \cap E \to Z$ has no critical points, where $E$ is the exceptional divisor and $\tilde{X}$ is the strict transform of $X$.

Is it true that $\tilde{X}$ is smooth?

Comment: I don't understand the assumption about critical points. Do you just mean that $\tilde{X} \cap E$ is smooth?

Comment: @Sasha I mean that $\tilde{X}\cap E$ is an unramified covering of $Z$ under $\pi$. Since $Z$ is one dimensional, then $\tilde{X}\cap E$ must be a disjoint union of lines.

Comment: $\tilde{X} \cap E$ is a divisor in $\tilde{X}$, so its dimension is $n - 2$; it can't be a union of lines unless $n = 3$.

Comment: @Sasha You are right. I mean that the map is a disjoint union of copies of $Z$. Can we conclude that $\tilde{X}$ smooth?

Comment: What does $\operatorname{Sing}(X) = Z$ mean? When $X$ is a hypersurface, its singular locus has dimension at most $n-2$. Do you mean that it is the intersection of $X$ with $Z$?

Comment: I mean that $X=V(f)$ for some $f$, and $V(\partial_1(f), \dots, \partial_n(f))=Z$, where $\partial_i(f)$ is the $i$-th partial derivative of $f$. For example $f(x,y,z) =x^3-y^3z$.

Answer (score 4):

The following simple observation is quite useful: if $D \subset Y$ is a Cartier divisor and $D$ is smooth, then $Y$ is smooth along $D$. Indeed, for each point $y \in D$ one has
$$
\dim Y - 1 = \dim D = \dim T_y D \ge \dim T_y Y - 1 \ge \dim Y - 1
$$
(where the first inequality uses the Cartier property), hence inequalities are equalities, in particular $\dim T_y Y = \dim Y$, i.e., $Y$ is smooth at $y$.

Now you can apply this observation to $Y = \tilde{X}$ and $D = \tilde{X} \cap E$. This is a Cartier divisor (because $E$ is), and it is smooth (by your assumption). Therefore, $\tilde{X}$ is smooth along $D$. And away from $D$ it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^n$, hence also smooth.